# Displaying Image caption with only HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to display caption on images.

This is my HTML

```
            <div class="image-hover">               

                <div class="image-block">
                    <a href="" target="_blank" class="image-overlay">
                        <div class="details">
                            <h4>Our philosophy and Vision</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="image-backdrop">
                            <img src="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/mosaic/omr-office.jpg"/>
                        </div>                          
                    </a>
                </div>                      

                <div class="image-block">
                    <a href="" target="_blank" class="image-overlay">
                        <div class="details">
                            <h4>Our philosophy and Vision</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="image-backdrop">
                            <img src="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/mosaic/omr-office.jpg"/>
                        </div>                          
                    </a>
                </div>                      

                <div class="image-block">
                    <a href="" target="_blank" class="image-overlay">
                        <div class="details">
                            <h4>Our philosophy and Vision</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="image-backdrop">
                            <img src="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/mosaic/omr-office.jpg"/>
                        </div>                          
                    </a>
                </div>                      

                <div class="image-block">
                    <a href="" target="_blank" class="image-overlay">
                        <div class="details">
                            <h4>Our philosophy and Vision</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="image-backdrop">
                            <img src="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/mosaic/omr-office.jpg"/>
                        </div>                          
                    </a>
                </div>                      


            </div>
```

This is my CSS :

```
.image-hover {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-hover .image-block {
    width: 234px;
    height: 100px;  
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #666666;

}

.image-hover .image-block img {
    width: 230px;
    height: 100px;  
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.details, .image-backdrop {
    float: left;
}

.details h4:after {
    display: inline-block;
  content:" ";
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid #666666;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

This is my [JsFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/ADMvd/)

My problem is how can I get image's caption to above of image? 
Any comments are greatly welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `position:relative;` to the container and `position:absolute;` to the child container whom you want to on image it is styled as you want

http://jsfiddle.net/ADMvd/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS

```
.details h4 {
    color: white; /* just to make it look pretty */
}
.details {
    position: absolute;
}
.image-overlay {
    position: relative;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/ADMvd/1/)

## EDIT

Note that you are using `div` tag inside your `a` tag so don't forget to add `display: block` to your `a.image-overlay` tag because `inline` elements can't contain any other type of elements. It does work but will cause many weird problems.

For starters `height:100%` won't work for `div` inside `a`